# Cashu /Payment gateway post data to merchant url

Tags: c#, asp.net, response, payment-gateway

I am using Cashu Payment Gateway. Hereby for the return page after succesful transaction the integration guide says

CASHU uses the HTTP POST to submit the following data to the Merchant’s Return URL.

amount
Same amount sent by the Merchant.
currency
Same currency sent by the Merchant

i am not able to hanlde the response using request.form or other method.Implementing this first time on c#.

Kindly let me know how to handle the response in c#

Comment: *i am not able to handle the response using request.form* <- Why not? what happens? is the request empty? Is the URL called at all? If it is implement a diagnostics trace or sniffer to see what's being sent

Comment: its shows empty the url which is sending me the response is https://www.cashu.com/cgi-bin/payment.cgi  but i didnt know how to read. Response is there in post i can give you the para which shows what they are sending